# heroku "initialize" operation time out error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm using rails 3.1.1 and I've been trying to run command as console and rake but I faced with an Error like

```
Running console attached to terminal... 
/Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/
heroku-2.17.0/lib/heroku/client/
rendezvous.rb:33:in `initialize': 
Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
```

What's the problem? Anyone knows?

Comment: Has it worked before or is this your first time trying?

Comment: the first time. It hasn't been worked yet.

Answer (score 6):

There's a few troubleshooting points at http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oneoff-admin-ps#troubleshooting - typically it's a problem connecting on port 5000 if you're behind a firewall.

Comment: yes. I'm behind the firewall. damn! I hope it wouldn't be the reason. I'm trying for hours :(

Comment: can I change Port 5000 to something?

Comment: no, that's the port you connect to at Heroku - it's 5000 I'm afraid.

Comment: now I've tried to connect telnet s1.runtime.heroku.com 5000 and the response like that Trying 107.20.246.116...
ctelnet: connect to address 107.20.246.116: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
is it port 5000 error?